# Adding custom folder to asset pipeline in Grails

Tags: grails, asset-pipeline

I have a Grails application. I have the js, css and image folder in the web-app and in the same folder I have a themes folder. I am planning to use the asset pipeline plugin. How should I use my themes folder? I have files with the same names in the core folders and the themes folder. 
Any help on this?

Comment: Did my answer help with your issue?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Custom folders are supported in the asset pipeline. I will show you an example using Bootstrap.

We create a root level directory in the assets folder called themes, this is where we will store third party scripts. You can name this anything you like, E.G., lib, libraries, vendor, plugins.

```
assets/
    images/
    javascript/
        application.js
    stylesheets/
        application.css
    themes/
        bootstrap/
            js/
                bootstrap.js
                bootstrap.min.js
            css/
                bootstrap.css
                bootstrap.min.css
```

You can then access these files from the custom folder like so:

```
// application.js
//= require bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js

// application.css
/*= require bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css */

// In a gsp
<asset:javascript src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js"/>
```

The require directives ignore the first directory in the asset folder. This allows you to modularise and organise your assets nicely.

You might need to restart your grails application when adding a new top level asset directory.

Comment: Thanks..let me try this.

Comment: I am not able to minify them in the development mode.

Comment: No, this will be done when you package the application into a war file.

Comment: If you want to find out how to minify in development mode then I suggest you raise another question.