# Assets pipeline on Grails

Tags: html, grails, asset-pipeline

I'm using grails 2.5.x.

I'm gonna import the themes to project.

However, images, js, css contain in many subfolder in theme. So there're a lot of file to add to assets/images, assets/css, assets/stylesheet.

Is there possible way to add the whole theme folder to project, using assets pipeline.

Any solution will be appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Adding custom folder to asset pipeline in Grails](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32132532/adding-custom-folder-to-asset-pipeline-in-grails)

Answer (score 1):

Sure thing. Those folders are strictly for organizational purposes. Typically when i have a bundled theme or library with multiple asset types i create an `grails-app/assets/libs` folder and just copy it into there. Asset-pipeline does not actually restrict what file types go where. that first folder is for organization and is flattened so just make a generic vendor or libs folder and throw it in.