# Web-App Folder Missing in new Grails Version

Tags: grails

We used to keep resource files like js, css and user upload files inside the folder Web-App in older grails project. but new grails gradle project structure doesn't have the folder web-app instead it has assets pipeline.

Please advice where to keep the resource file and how to access the files.

Comment: Did you try the plugin [http://grails.org/plugin/asset-pipeline](http://grails.org/plugin/asset-pipeline)? It provides you with a `assets` folder within the `grails-app` folder. There I have a `images`, `javascript`, and `stylesheets` folder. For full packages I use the `lib` folder.

Comment: FYI... For js and css files in particular the recommendations to use `asset-pipeline` are valid.  For resources in general, you might want some things in `src/main/resources/`.  There are a variety of things that would typically go there.

Comment: Thanks, Found some more details about my question here [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32132532](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32132532/adding-custom-folder-to-asset-pipeline-in-grails)

Answer (score 0):

Use `asset pipeline` for your resources.

Place them in the coressponding directories under `grails-app\assets`, such as `stylesheets` and `javascript`. Then use the tag library provided by `asset pipeline` to include them in your `gsp` files. For example: `<asset:stylesheet src="some.css" />` and `<asset:javascript src="some.js" />`.

There are a great number of other features included with `asset pipeline` and I highly recommend you read the [documentation](http://bertramdev.github.io/grails-asset-pipeline/).